# Get list related objects

Tags: python, django

I have model like (it is many to many relation):

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = moddels.CharField(max_length=255)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    user1 = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_set')
    user2 = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I want get for some user list objects which related to `user2` field. How i can do it?

I can't use ManyToMany field.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, what do you mean `get for some user list objects which related to user2 field`?

Comment: I want use it like `request.user.user_set.get_related_users()` and it have to return all `user2` for which `user1=request.user`

Comment: With given code you can do: [u.user2 for u in request.user.user_set.all()] and have the list you want.

Comment: What have you tried? Please edit your question to include your failing code and a clear explanation or example of the output you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not be able to get the whole user objects in one query, but you could get the ids of the related `user2`:

```
user2_ids = request.user.user_set.all().values_list('user2', flat=True).distinct()
```

If you really need whole objects, you could do one more step:

```
user2s = User.objects.filter(id__in=user2_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the `user2` attribute a `related_name` as well:

```
user2 = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user2s')
```

Then you can find them using `user.user2s.all()` et cetera.